# How to debug a .NET web service that receives null instead of the expected object

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, rest

I have a web service in C#/.NET that looks like this. The problem is that this method in the controller receives `null` as the `Form12 form` argument, instead of the expected object.

```
    [Route("create/")]
    public ApiResponse<int> createRecord(Form12 form)
    {
        if (form == null)
            return error<int>(message: "Received null object as input.");

        //real code here
    }
```

The declaration for the Form12 class contains about 250 members, like this:

```
public class Form12: BaseModel
{
    public Form12()
    {
        this.Key = new List<string>();
        this.Key.Add("ID");
        this.AutoIncrement="ID";
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ItemID { get; set; }

    public string BranchCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime RequestDate { get; set; }

    //250 more members declared in the same way - string, int, DateTime only
```

When I debug from Swagger UI, the `createRecord()` method in the controller receives a non-null object.

When I make the call from the real page, the method receives `null` as the form parameter. It works, however, if I POST using only a few variables (ID, BranchCode etc.). When I POST all the 250+ variables, the `Form12` is null.

Apparently there is some mismatch between my POST request an the `Form12` definition.

How can I even approach debugging this? There is no error message, there are no logs - my controller just gets a null as the parameter. I can see the request in Chrome Dev Tools, but it's not really helpful - there are 250+ variables in the object sent in the POST request, as expected.

Update: I can get a non-null object as follows, but the conversion to my model still fails:

```
    public ApiResponse<int> createRecord(dynamic form_temp)
    {
        var form = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Form12>(form_temp);
```

Comment: You can try using Fiddler or the browser debugging tools (i use firebug for FireFox) to see what happens under the hood.

Comment: But that's happening on the other side, in C#. I assume that the web service cannot convert my POST request into the model object.

Comment: Fiddler will show you whats going on on the post request if its sends any data or just null , if it sends something you'll might be able to see whats wrong with it.

Comment: @HagayGoshen I can see that it sends the data via Chrome's dev tools. If I change the object type in the C# controller to `dynamic`, I can also see that it receives the data. The error occurs somewhere where .NET converts the POSTed data into my model.

Comment: If so i would strip properties on the client side object (just comment them) until the server can successfully convert them , then add them step by step till it cant and you'll find your problem.

Comment: @HagayGoshen did that, it worked.